# How to edit the LinkButton visibility within a GridViewEdit in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, linkbutton

I wonder how to edit a the visibility of a LinkButton within a GridViewEdit:

I have got a LinkButton named "lbtnActivateConfig" in the ItemTemplate of a GridView in my aspx-File:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnActivateConfig" runat="server"
       OnClick="GridViewDeactivate" Visible="false">Deaktivieren
  </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now I want to change the visibility of the LinkButton insite this method:

```
protected void GridViewEdit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = this.ConfigGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

        LinkButton buttonActivate = (LinkButton)ConfigGridView.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lbtnActivateConfig");
        buttonActivate.Visible = true;
    }
```

While debugging it catches the LinkButton an seems to set it's visibility. But the LinkButton is still invisible.

It's the same if I change the button to visible inside the aspx-File and try to change it in the method.

For me it seems that the aspx-File is always executed at last and overwrites the changes in the method. Is this right? How can I change the visibility inside the method? Any ideas?

Thank you and Goodbye!

Comment: Have you turned viewstate off?

Comment: @Christoph: I see that you are new. Welcome to Stack Overflow! On each question you ask, if any of the answers help you please upvote them by clicking the up arrow next to that answer. If an answer answers your question, please mark it as you accepted answer by clicking the large check next to that question. For more information, see the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Thanks for welcome. ;) I think I understand the system, I'm reading on stackoverflow since years.

@Ben: I did not use the ViewState in this case. What has it to do with my problem and how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
protected void GridViewEdit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = this.ConfigGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    (ConfigGridView.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lbtnActivateConfig")).Visible = true;      
}
```

You don't need to cast it as `LinkButton` because all controls have the `Visible` property. And when you set `FindControl` to a variable, the variable is set by value rather than by reference which means you aren't referring to the actual control.

Comment: It's right that I do not need the LinkButton but this do not fix my problem. The code is more compact but the visibility stays false.

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on how you implement the edits on the grid view, you will need the button to be in the `<EditItemTemplate>` (I think that's what it's called) or it will not be accessible when a row is being edited.

Comment: I found a workaround for the problem, without fixing it. Anyway, thanks for your help!